# Java Synchronized on object or variable?

Tags: java, object, reference, synchronized

Ok, I will try to phrase this clearly.   Is the object synchronization on the object itself, or the reference to the object?

That is, if I have

```
Object lock1 = new Object();
Object lock2 = lock1;
```

will a block `synchronized (lock1)` block code `synchronized (lock2)`?

Both are referring to the same actual object, just with different references...

I *think* that it is the object that matters, not the reference, but I am not certain.

Thank you.

Comment: The monitor is associated with the object itself. So yes, if a thread is in a `synchronized (lock1)` block then another thread will have to wait to enter a `synchronized (lock2)` block.

Comment: The object. Otherwise a reference from another thread with a different reference could ignore the synchronization.

Comment: I think there might be some confusion as to what a reference is in java context.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object lock1 = new Object();
Object lock2 = lock1;
```

> Both are referring to the same actual object, just with different references...

This is incorrect, the value of non-primitives in Java is the reference to the instance.
Therefore, both are referring to **the same Object** with **the same reference**.

You can assign that Object to any variable you like and using a synchronized block will synchronize on that Object instance. The lock monitors are on Object instances themselves.

You can see a bit of evidence of that when take a look at the methods of the Object class related to locking. Here is the notify method used to notify threads that are waiting for the lock to be freed so they can execute the synchronized block:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()

Comment: Up voting mostly for the point about references being the same.  This kind'a makes the original question semi-moot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It was what I was expecting, but I was not confident. 
 Still ... a follow up question then ... when I used the word "reference" I was talking about the variables "java1" vs. "java2".  If reference is NOT the proper word there, what would have been?  I was trying to make the distinction between the variables and the object they were referring to ... but apparently I missed something?

Comment: variable, constant, etc.